# AS3 FileReference.save() works when testing locally but not in the browser

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, filereference

I have created a painting app and when the user want's to save his drawing he simply hits the save button and a dialog pops up - or should do.

When testing locally on dev machine it's no problem but whenever the app is loaded in a browser it won't work. Even if I load the local SWF file in a browser it won't work.

The following code is what I use to save the file and as said it works fine locally but whenever it goes into a browser it dosen't.The save dialog simply never pops up.

Any suggestions?

```
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
bitmapData.draw(canvas);
var jpg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(100);
var ba:ByteArray = jpg.encode(bitmapData);

file = new FileReference();
file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileSaveComplete);
file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, error);
file.save(ba, 'FileName.jpg');
```

Running FlashPlayer 11 and compiling to 10.2 BTW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a security issue. A save file dialog window can now only be opened as a result to a direct user event, like a click. One solution is to notify the user when the image is created, and ask if he wants to save the file locally. And if he clicks yes, you call the **save** method.

Here's more info on this change:

http://www.bogdanmanate.com/2010/05/12/flex-error-2176-when-using-filereference/

Hope this helps. Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code I pasted above is called from a Custom Event I created and that's why it's not working. I changed it so it's called from a MouseEvent a there we go! Good day to you too.

Comment: Great! It might be an annoying feature, but it really prevents some nasty stuff.

Comment: On a side note, doesn't it throw and error in the debug player if you try to call FileReference.save() without a UIA?

Comment: I didn't try a try & catch statement but at least it did not throw the IOErrorEvent which I was listening for. If just it threw that I would have had something to aim for...