# How set wallpaper in flash as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, wallpaper

Who can help me to make the photo On the desktop ..For example, to save the image in the stage in Flash and make it a background in desktop(in flash function to make an image as wallpaper)or background in phone Using the button thanks..

[image: as an example]

Comment: If you are using AIR, you can find or write an ANE (native extension) to accomplish this.  If you are using Flash Player, it will not be possible.

Looks like your trying to use this ANE?
http://flashvisions.com/how-to-set-wallpaper-on-android-with-adobe-air/

Comment: @LDMS: Thanks very much
  If possible I want to illustrate an example in which b Fla cs6 + AS3

Comment: @LDMS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915396/add-a-button-to-save-the-picture-in-air-or-as3

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set an image in flash to become your desktops wall paper. You can adjust the images size and parameters via flash and export, then you will have to set it as our desktop wallpaper manually.

Answer (score 0):

For the desktop platform, you can encode the image into an OS-readable format (PNG, JPG, others depend on OS) and call `FileReference.save()` with the encoded `ByteArray`. This will invoke the OS-specific dialogue of "Save as" where the user will have to input the proper name for the file **with its extension** (if OS requires an extension), so you will have to hint the user of what type of file he will receive. For this, you can name your button "Save as PNG", for example. A code example is [here in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293648/as3-filereference-save-works-when-testing-locally-but-not-in-the-browser).